# Exportar directorios de listado recursivo

Tags: java, apache-poi

Estoy haciendo un recorrido recursivo de directorios y quiero exportar los directorios y los archivos encontrados a un archivo de excel. Este es mi código

```
package packages;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class hh {

    public void leer(String inicio, String altura) {
        File ar = new File(inicio);
        String[] dir = ar.list();
        XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = book.createSheet();
        for (int f = 0; f < dir.length; f++) {
            File ar2 = new File(inicio + dir[f]);
            String sss = "Directorio: " + dir[f];
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(f);

            if (ar2.isFile()) {
                //System.out.println(altura + dir[f]);
            }
            if (ar2.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println(altura + "Directorio:" + dir[f]);
                for (int j = 0; j < dir.length; j++) {
                    XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(j);
                    cell.setCellValue(sss);
                }
                leer(inicio + dir[f] + "\\", altura + "  ");
            }

        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\jdjdj.xlsx"));
            book.write(out);
            System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        hh rec = new hh();
        rec.leer("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\internacionales\\", "");
    }
}
```

Cuando se genera el archivo .xlsx solo me muestra las carpetas principales, es decir, las primeras carpetas que encuentra en la ruta que especifique. Quiero imprimir todas las subcarpetas en un archivo excel

Comment: Hola @S.Bruce. Bienvenido al sitio. Por favor indica qué dificultad tienes con este código, cuál es el problema específico que tienes: leer las carpetas, escribir las carpetas, almacenar las carpetas en alguna estructura, escribir en el archivo Excel, etc.

Comment: Hola Luiggi. El código me permite recorrer las carpetas sin ningún problema el problema esta cuando quiero imprimir las carpetas en un archivo excel. Cuando me genera el archivo xlsx solo me imprime las carpetas principales no me imprime las subcarpetas de las carpetas principales ni las subcarpetas de las subcarpetas.

Answer (score 1):

La librería *Apache Commons IO* tiene la clase *FileUtils* que te ofrece una gran cantidad de métodos de utilidad para trabajar con ficheros y directorios, en tu caso concreto el método ***public static Collection <File> listFilesAndDirs(File directory, IOFileFilter fileFilter, IOFileFilter dirFilter)*** te ofrece lo que estas buscando, el código sería:

```
Collection<File> directorios=FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(new File(inicio), DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY,TrueFileFilter.TRUE);
```

Aquí tienes una colección de Files que son todos los directorios encontrados de forma recursiva.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás llamando al método de manera recursiva y en cada llamada escribes el libro en una salida física, denotado en estas partes:

```
public void leer(String inicio, String altura) {
    //...
    XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(); //<- creas el archivo Excel en memoria, local al método
    //..
    for (int f = 0; f < dir.length; f++) {
        //...
        if (ar2.isDirectory()) {
            //...
            leer(inicio + dir[f] + "\\", altura + "  "); //<- llamada recursiva al método
        }
    }
    try {
        //...
        book.write(out); //<- escribes el libro Excel local al método en disco
        //...
    } //...
}
```

Lo mejor que puedes hacer es mover la creación y escritura del libro Excel fuera del método, pasar la variable que maneja el libro Excel como parámetro al método y escribir el archivo luego de ejecutar el método, de esta manera:

```
public class hh {

    public void leer(String inicio, String altura, XSSFWorkbook book) {
        File ar = new File(inicio);
        String[] dir = ar.list();
        for (int f = 0; f < dir.length; f++) {
            File ar2 = new File(inicio + dir[f]);
            String sss = "Directorio: " + dir[f];
            XSSFSheet sheet = book.getSheetAt(0);
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1);
            if (ar2.isFile()) {
                //System.out.println(altura + dir[f]);
            }
            if (ar2.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println(altura + "Directorio:" + dir[f]);
                for (int j = 0; j < dir.length; j++) {
                    XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(j);
                    cell.setCellValue(sss);
                }
                leer(inicio + dir[f] + "\\", altura + "  ");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        hh rec = new hh();
        XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = book.createSheet();
        rec.leer("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\internacionales\\", "", book);
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\jdjdj.xlsx"));
            book.write(out);
            System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");
            book.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Luiggi. Hay un error con en la linea   `leer(inicio + dir[f] + "\\", altura + "  ");`  falta un parámetro. Si le doy como tercer parámetro "book" sigue imprimiendo las primeras carpetas que encuentra.